Regenerating ActionText content attribute embedded urls after creation (Rails 7.2, Trix, ActionText, S3)
I have a Rails 7.2 app that uses ActionText to handle rich text attributes of several models.  On the front end (a react native app), I use the Trix editor to support image attachment, and I've got js code to handle direct upload to S3 using presigned urls.  Ok so far.
Later, after the url signatures expire, the images become unretrievable as you'd expect.  What I need to do is tell ActionText to regenerate the embedded urls when that attribute's object is rendered.
For example, if you inspect the attribute content.body, after saving to the database you'll see something like this:
<div class="trix-content">
  <div>
<span></span>
<action-text-attachment content-type="image/jpeg" url="https://xxxxxx-general-development.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/848eba6xxxxxxb1172533e8f821.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXBMJBExxxx4XPA%2F20240822%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20240822T172814Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=336978da6925eb1d8423634xxxxxa1947010f4275772754805" href="https://xxxxx-general-development.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/848eba657xxxxxx33e8f821.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXBMxxxxx4XPA%2F20240822%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20240822T172814Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=336978da6925eb1d842xxxxxxxxxe5734a1947010f4275772754805" filename="IMG_0111.jpeg" filesize="4127057" width="4032" height="3024" presentation="gallery"><figure class="attachment attachment--preview">
  <img width="4032" height="3024" src="https://xxxxxeneral-development.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/848eba657a17exxxxx1172533e8f821.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXBMJBExxxx20240822%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20240822T172814Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=336978da6925exxxxx00a23bf6f417e5734a1947010f4275772754805">
</figure></action-text-attachment><span></span><br>Sadfasdfasdfasdf!<br><br>

The key here is this:
src="https://xxx.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/848ebxxxx33e8f821.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXBxxxx0240822%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20240822T172814Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=336978da6925eb1d8423634c900xxx0f4275772754805"

in the  element.
How do I tell ActionText to rerender the rich text content with new set of signed signature fields?  I know how to create those fields, but I don't know how to pass them into ActionText dynamically.
